# TailTruncation is not working with OHAttributedLable

Tags: iphone, word-wrap

I am having OHAttributedLable like following

```
    lblHeaderTitle =[[OHAttributedLabel alloc]init];
    [lblHeaderTitle setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [lblHeaderTitle setFrame:CGRectMake(15, 8,(WidthForBoldText(txt1))+45, height)];

    //[lblHeaderTitle setNumberOfLines:2];
    [lblHeaderTitle setLineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation];
    [lblHeaderTitle setNumberOfLines:0];
    lblHeaderTitle.attributedText = attrStr;
```

it is displaying all in one line and remaining part is not visible

now the problem is that i am not able to wrap or truncate text in this lable can anybody help me with this.
what i want is if my text is

"Abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" then it will display

"Abcdefghijklmn..." or

"Abcdefghijklmn

opqrstuvwxyz"

anything will work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try setting numberoflines to 1? When you set it to 0 it becomes multiline.

Comment: Thanks Praveen for prompt reply, i have just tried but no good news

Comment: see i have updated the question, just below the code

Comment: Try setting the adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth and number of lines to 1.

Comment: tried but not working...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611816/multi-line-nsattributedstring-with-truncated-text

Comment: linebreakmode ,numberifline and adjustFontsizeToFitWidht all are not supported by OHAttributedLable

Answer (score 0):

```
lableName.numberOfLines = 0;

lableName.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
```